# Python "Magic methods" are realy methods?

Tags: python, object, methods

I know how to use magical methods in python, but I would like to understand more about them.

For it I would like to consider three examples:

1) `__init__`:

We use this as constructor in the beginning of most classes. If this is a method, what is the object associated with it? Is it a basic python object that is used to generate all the other objects?

2) `__add__`
We use this to change the behaviour of the operator `+`. The same question above.

3) `__name__`:
The most common use of it is inside this kind of structure:`if __name__ == "__main__":`

This is return True when you are running the module as the main program.

My question is `__name__`  a method or  a variable? If it is a variable what is the method associated with it. If this is a method, what is the object associated with it?

Since I do not understand very well these methods, maybe the questions are not well formulated. I would like to understand how these methods are constructed in Python.

Comment: In a nutshell, Python does certain things at certain times with things named a certain way. Those “certain names” are virtually all such dunder-scored words, which is the convention for “Python’s special stuff”. `__init__` gets called, if present, around object construction time. A module’s `__name__` is set by the system, etc…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `__init__` is *not* a constructor; it is an *initializer*, invoked automatically (usually) on the return value of `__new__` (which *is* a constructor).

  `x = Foo()` is roughly equivalent to

  ```
  x = Foo.__new__(Foo)
  Foo.__init__(x)
  ```
- `x + y` is equivalent to `x.__add__(y)` or `type(x).__add__(x, y)`
- `__name__` is not a method; it's a `str`-valued module-level attribute that contains the name of the current  module.

Answer (score 1):

1. The object is the class that's being instantiated, a.k.a. the `Foo` in `Foo.__init__(actual_instance)`
2. In `a + b` the object is `a`, and the expression is equivalent to `a.__add__(b)`
3. `__name__` is a variable. It can't be a method because then comparisons with a string would *always* be `False` since a function is never equal to a string

Comment: Yeah, I don't see *that* much difference between our two answers. (Clearly, two different voters involved.)

Comment: That first statement certainly seems weird… Do you mean `self` is not the instance? Otherwise, what “the object” do you mean?

Comment: @deceze, "the object" was meant to be the `Foo` in `Foo.__init__(instance)`, and `self` is the argument